# Use dependency command line parameters with maven build

Tags: maven, findbugs

I am using `findbugs-maven-plugin` in the verify phase of the maven life cycle. i.e. it runs on `mvn clean install`. This is the code I have in my parent `pom.xml` (in a multi-module project).

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>findbugs</id>
           <phase>verify</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>check</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>target/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>

 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>verify</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>transform</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
     <configuration>
        <transformationSets>
           <transformationSet>
              <dir>target/findbugs</dir>
              <outputDir>target/findbugs</outputDir>
              <stylesheet>plain.xsl</stylesheet>
              <fileMappers>
                 <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                 <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
                 </fileMapper>
              </fileMappers>
           </transformationSet>
       </transformationSets>
     </configuration>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
             <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
             <version>2.0.0</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This is working fine and html files are being generated in each module target. However I want to take this a step further by being able to use parameters allowed by findbugs during the maven build (for example `onlyAnalyze`). I do not want to add configuration in the `pom.xml`.

I want the build process to remain the same unless I specify by some command that I want to analyze only one class, for example by running:

```
mvn clean install -Dfindbugs:onlyAnalyze=MyClass
```

Do you know of a way I can do this?

Comment: I think you forgot some code..

Comment: yeah haha included it now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can call a standalone goal:
`plugin-prefix:goal` or `groupId:artifactId:version:goal` to ensure the right version.
In your case: `findbugs:findbugs`

With `-Dkey=value` you can set plugin parameters *if* they are exposed. http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html doesn't show that option. Just to compare: http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/help-mojo.html does have such options. Here it is still called `Expression` with `${key}`, nowadays it's generated as `User property` with just `key`.

If you want onlyAnalyze to be set from commandline, either ask the mojo-team to fix that, or do the following:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <findbugs.onlyAnalyze>false</findbugs.onlyAnalyze> <!-- default value -->
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <configuration>
        <onlyAnalyze>${findbugs.onlyAnalyze}</onlyAnalyze>
      </configuration>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Now you can call `mvn findbugs:findbugs -Dfindbugs.onlyAnalyze=true`